# CSS code acting weird in phone but not in browser

Tags: css, html, ionic-framework

I'm using the Ionic framework and I have the following CSS code:

```
.witzle-bg-image {
  background-image: url('../img/home-bg.png');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
}
```

And it does exactly what it should in Google Chrome: it resizes so that the background image is always covering the screen. When I run it on my Android though, it starts repeating at the bottom. When I put `no-repeat` there is just a blank white area. I thought `background-size:cover` was supposed to stop that.

Comment: cover and fixed won't go really well together as you can read here
http://www.carsonshold.com/2013/02/css-background-sizecover-doesnt-like-fixed-positioning/

Comment: even if i take out the 'fixed' the problem persists

Comment: actually, if i take it out the problem occurs in a browser as well...weird

Comment: could you produce a fiddle?

Comment: which android version are you testing it? Old version you need -webkit-background-size

Comment: im runnning on 4.4.2, and i want it to be fixed because i want the bg relative to the viewport not the div

Comment: On what element you putting this class to?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I think you also facing the same. You need to put this class to the ion-content rather than ion-view. If you doing the same then we have hit the jackpot.

Code snippet:

```
.scroll-content{
  background-image: url('http://www.jimatkinsonwebdesign.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/google-chrome.jpg');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
}
```

The [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gxDBf) link is attached. Hope it helps!!